# Randomly lost ZSH prompt settings

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

Yesterday I suddenly lost all my ZSH settings more specifically the prompt and how the themes as they are applied. I've tried the following so far:

1. As suggested in the ZSH FAQs, I tried `exec zsh` but that only works in the current terminal. Even if I open a new terminal tab, the process isn't running there.
2. Uninstall and reinstall ZSH. Nothing changed.
3. Tried adding a different prompt format to the `.zshrc` file. It also only worked when I ran `exec zsh`. That leads me to believe that the config file isn't being read but I can't figure out how to correct the issue.

I'm not sure what information would be helpful in this situation so not sure what else to share. I'll update the question with more info as it goes.

Basic info:

OS: MacOS Monterey 12.6.1 
Mac: MacBook Pro 2021 (2021)

Thank you for your help in advance.

Edit:

Ran `zsh -o sourcetrace` and this was the output:

```
+/etc/zshrc:1> <sourcetrace>
+/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.zshrc:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/tools/check_for_upgrade.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/cache/.zsh-update:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/compfix.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.zcompdump-sanieakhtar-5.8.1:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/bzr.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/cli.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/clipboard.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/compfix.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/completion.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/correction.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/diagnostics.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/directories.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/functions.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/git.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/grep.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/cache/grep-alias:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/history.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/key-bindings.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/misc.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/nvm.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/prompt_info_functions.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/spectrum.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/termsupport.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/lib/vcs_info.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/custom/example.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/Users/sanieakhtar/.oh-my-zsh/themes/robbyrussell.zsh-theme:1> <sourcetrace>
```

Comment: [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/) tells you what files you should be changing

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a go. But I don't understand how I even lost these settings. Why do I need to change anything so far away from `.zshrc` anyway? And what should I even start changing?

Comment: @DavidPostill The article you linked states
"Moral: For zsh, put stuff in ~/.zshrc, which is always executed."
But I don't think my `.zshrc` is being executed. I always have to do it manually..

Comment: Is the shell for your userid still set to `zsh`? Try `echo $0` to see.

Comment: Yes, it returns `zsh`.

Comment: “ But I don't think my .zshrc is being executed. I always have to do it manually..”: In your `sourcetrace` output, it clearly shows that your `.zshrc` file _is_ being executed.

Comment: “ Even if I open a new terminal tab, the process isn't running there.” What process?

Comment: “Yesterday I suddenly lost all my ZSH settings more specifically the prompt and how the themes as they are applied.” Your `sourcetrace` shows that OMZ is being loaded, including the `git` plugin and the `robbyrussel` prompt theme. What settings & prompt did you lose. And how did you lose “ how the themes as they are applied”? What do you mean with that?

Comment: Oh, and don’t answer me here; update your question.

Comment: I'll update with screenshots

Answer (score 0):

You can put Zsh in debug mode by starting it with

```bash
zsh -xo sourcetrace
```

Then you’ll see all the files that get loaded and all the code that gets executed when you start up your shell.

Comment: I tried this. There's so many commands that get executed and so many files that are loaded. Any hints on what I should be looking for?

Comment: @potatoheadgear What output do you get from `zsh -o sourcetrace`?

Comment: I will edit my question because the output is too long to be posted as a comment..